# WebView does not render css like the browser does?

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

As far as im aware, the WebView is the same thing as the built in browser? Right?

I am facing an issue where a page that contains some absolute positioned div elements all stack on top of eachother instead of finding their correct location, AND background-image gets completely ignored.

This said, in the browser on my phone (HTC Incredible S - 2.3.3, stock browser) renders it out correctly, and on top of this, applications that use an embedded webview that i can point it to the page, renders correctly. Which leads me to beleive that the webview I have in my application is bjorking somehow.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.*;

public class ShowWebView extends Activity {

    public WebView web;
    public String baseURL = "http://test.dev/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webpage);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webpage);
        home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tool_Home);
        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tool_Back);
        forward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tool_Forward);
        refresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tool_Refresh);

        ajax = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_anim);
        ajax.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ajax_animation);


        // Settings
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {

            String url = baseURL+extras.getString("page")+"?androidApplication"; // The Basics, page gets added to baseURL
            String id = "";
            String push = "false"; // false by default

            // If an ID exists, lets get it
            if(extras.getString("id") != null) {
                id = extras.getString("id");
            }

            if(extras.getString("push") != null) {
                push = extras.getString("push");
            }

            // Build the URL
            if(id != "") url = url + "&id="+id;
            if(push != "false")     url = url + "&pushVersion";

            web.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            web.loadUrl("http://www.bing.com");
        }
}
```

also heres my webview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/MainPage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/top_header" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SubHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/top_sub_header" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >








        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/webpage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 />

        </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2.5sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tool_Home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Home" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tool_Back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/backward" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tool_Forward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/forward" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tool_Refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/refresh" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

any help resolving this issue would be truly amazing!

Comment: I could suggest a couple troubleshooting ideas to help get some more information.  1.) When you say that it renders correctly on your phone's browser, just to make sure, is this phone the same place you are running your app? CSS support differs in different versions of Android.  2.) If you remove all the views and only have a WebView in your layout does it change anything?  3.) If you open other websites into your WebView  that have background positions and absolute positions (possibly websites with html/css examples) do the same problems exist, or is it just your html/css?

Comment: I thank you for your input as it lead me down the correct path! I found out what was happening, please check out my question above (at the very top) for the answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Helped me a lot. setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL) did the trick for me.

Comment: You should take the answer that you discovered and insert it as the answer below (then accept it), rather than making it an edit on your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently:

```
web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

was causing the webview to freak out, as it reorganizes the html renderer to place everything in a single column (or try to anyways). Disabling this line or using NORMAL causes the render to be just fine.

I was only using this line to disable horizontal scrolling. So now i have THAT issue to deal with again and still.

Comment: Tried everything and this finally worked for me. If you're having issues with CSS, try this. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, This line fixes the CSS issue rendering: `web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);` , +1 for the answer

Comment: `WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS`  is actually deprecated, use `WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL`